# How can we use ms office communicator client exposed APIs in python, is that possible?

Tags: python, api, office-communicator

I want to use ms office communicator client apis, and i wan to use those in python is it possible to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> import win32com.client
>>> msg = win32com.client.Dispatch('Communicator.UIAutomation')
>>> msg.InstantMessage('user@domain.com')
```

Comment: Any idea how to react to events?  When I try to use "DispatchWithEvents" instead of "Dispatch", I get an error: `ValueError: This COM object does not support events.`

Answer (score 1):

There is an JSON API to access all office communicator functions via "office communicator web access". You can [download](http://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=Microsoft+Office+Communicator+Web+Access+AJAX+Service) a description for that API. But nobody has implemented a module yet. The API is quiet complex.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know very well Ms Office communicator but if it exposes a COM interface, you shoudl be able to access it through the Mark Hammond python bindings for COM http://starship.python.net/crew/skippy/

Otherwise, if it exposes a .NET API you should be able to access it with IronPython

I hope it helps