# writing python script on windows 

Tags: python

I am new to python scripts .

I have few repetative testing tasks such logging to various IM's

ex (OCS,different public messengers) etc .

Is it possible to automate these tasks using python .

If so from where do I start with ?

Working on windows 2003 server .

I know the basics of python. want to enhance the skills .

Thanks,
Tazim

Comment: Sure it's possible. Do you have any prior experience in Python?

Comment: I think you'll be better off with batch or powershell scripting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## OCS

For OCS, you should be able to use COM scripting to do most but not all[1] things.  The code should look a bit like this:

```
import win32com.client

def get_contact(signin_uri, communicator):
   c = communicator.GetContact(signin_uri, communicator.MyServiceId)
   return c

comm = win32com.client.Dispatch('Communicator.UIAutomation')
contact = get_contact("jaya@contoso.com", comm)
```

You should be able to translate the documentation from the [API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb758755(v=office.12).aspx) fairly easily, especially if you focus on the JScript examples.

## MSN/Live, AIM, ICQ, and IRC

For MSN/Live Messenger, the excellent [twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/) library contains an [rudimentary implementation](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/TwistedWords) of a multiprotocol IM client (and server).  To get started, check out some [code samples](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/words/examples/).

---

[1] From the documentation:

> For reasons of security, not all
> methods or properties can be called
> using JavaScript or another scripting
> language. Such restrictions are
> documented in [Office Communicator Automation API Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb758755%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Not quite a duplicate question, but the answers to "[How can we use ms office communicator client exposed APIs in python, is that possible ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286790)" should prove valuable.

If you are new to Python, you'll want to check out the [Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/).

You may also wish to consider something a bit more Windows-oriented like VBScript or PowerShell,  however.

Comment: Given the baseline provided by the twisted.words library (see my answer), I think python is actually quite a good environment for implementing something like this.

Comment: @fmark: Indeed, `twisted` rocks (as does Python). I suggested that a Microsoft language may be considered (particularly if Python expertise is an issue and time-to-market is a concern).